# Struggling to Understand Vertices Behaviour 2

Tags: modeling, modifiers, vertices, mirror

[image: Image 1]
[image: Image 2]
[image: Image 3]

This is the second time I am posting this as I was unable to post the screenshots above the first time. I apologise.

[Blender Guru Anvil Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WxMwa0njGSM&list=PLjEaoINr3zgHJVJF3T3CFUAZ6z11jKg6a&t=1203s)

In the above link, the tutorial has a step a minute before the end in which he completes an extrusion with a clipping mirror modifier. At this point, the vertices at the ends of the semi-circle on the bottom of the anvil become locked to their actual vertex locations, instead of being near them due to the shade smooth and subsurf mod. I am unsure why this is occurring. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

you probably did press <kbd>E</kbd> and then <kbd>Esc</kbd>. That always results in duplicate vertices. If you dont undo that step and just carry on, you will be left with duplicate vertices in your final mesh, which will always break subsurf (will make a hard edge with lots and lots of duplicate vertices)

To fix it select everything and press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> and select "by Distance".

Comment: I took care to delete vertices but does this mean I’ve missed some extra ones then?

Comment: probably... just remember to hit Ctrl+Z everytime you aborted an extrusion. (Or did you mean my answer didn't work?) You can always check for duplicates by selecting a vertex and moving it. The duplicate should be left behind.